# Articles and verbs in error codes. What and when to use?

Tags: error-message, errors, ux-writing

Before we get to the question, I'm a beginner at UX writing and English is not my native language, so I apologize in advance for the wording.

I need to write texts for error codes, for example:

---

1. No response from (the) bank.

Try the following:

- Use another card.
- Try again later.

---

2. Transaction (was) rejected by the bank.

Seems like you (have) entered (the) wrong CVV code.

---

And I'm wondering if a should use articles and verbs here. Thanks for help!

Comment: All are fine either way except the last one. "Seems like" is much too informal. I would expect "It seems you have entered an indirect CVV code" or "CVV code appears to be incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a problem occurs we expect to know the following:

1. Problem.
2. Reason.
3. What to do.

This will help to decide what to use.

Your examples:

---

- *Problem:* Payment couldn't be completed.
- *Reason:* No response from (the) bank.
- *What to do:* Use another card or try again later.

---

- *Problem:* Payment couldn't be completed.
- *Reason:* Transaction (was) rejected by the bank.
- *What to do:* Check if you (have) entered (the) right CVV code.